# CSS Style Tag in Error Page

Tags: css, error, page-layout

I'm trying to change the body background color on an Error page only.  For whatever reason, it's not rendering my style tag.  I only need the background changed for this page..  Here is the code I placed in my aspx file, when I check devtools I don't even see the style tag in there.

```
<asp:Content ID="AdditionalPageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <style type="text/css"> 
    body{background:#fff;}
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Any difference using background-color property instead?

Comment: i'll try that one instead.

Comment: Chris, time for coffee. ``background`` is a CSS short-hand notation; so you can do things like: ``background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center;`` ... first parameter is always color